# Is there a tool (built-in or not) to parse `launchctl list` output to get one string?

Tags: command-line, launchd

I want to run a script based on one line in `launchctl list` output. I know there are ways to simplify this output using `awk` `sed` `grep` etc. The question is, is there a native or non-native tool for parsing this output? (It would be helpful if I just knew the name of the output format so I could do a search for that)

`launchctl list` outputs in this format:

```
% sudo launchctl list com.privateinternetaccess.vpn.daemon 
Password:
{
    "LimitLoadToSessionType" = "System";
    "Label" = "com.privateinternetaccess.vpn.daemon";
    "OnDemand" = false;
    "LastExitStatus" = 0;
    "PID" = 35114;
    "Program" = "/Applications/Private Internet Access.app/Contents/MacOS/pia-daemon";
    "ProgramArguments" = (
        "/Applications/Private Internet Access.app/Contents/MacOS/pia-daemon";
    );
};
```

Essentially this is a semi-colon delimited list inside of curly brackets - sorry don't know the name of this output format.

Right now I am getting by with these commands to get the PID, but as stated I would like to use tools specifically for this output format if they exist.

```
% sudo launchctl list com.privateinternetaccess.vpn.daemon  | grep PID | egrep -o  -e '[0-9]{1,}'
35114
```

My intention is to run a script based on whether this daemon is currently active or not. My initial thought was to get the PID and use that to determine if it was running as I understand a running daemon has a PID and otherwise it does not. Using an `if...fi` statement should do the trick.

Comment: I'd use `awk` as it eliminates the need to _pipe_ `grep/egrep` twice: `launchctl list com.privateinternetaccess.vpn.daemon | awk -F '= |;' '/PID/{print $2}'`

Comment: @user3439894 is this output in an "array". Are their native tools for accessing "fields" in this array?

Comment: No the _curly braces_ in the _output_ represent a _Dictionary_ in the **binary XML Plist** or **XML Plist** of which the _meta data_ is stored. In that particular _output_ the _parentheses_ represent an _Array_. This type of _command line output_ is the same as if using the `defaults read` _command_ on a `.plist` _file_. As you can see by my _example_ `awk` _command_ it is very efficient at parsing the _output_ to get the target _meta data_ and it one of the native tools of choice for such an operation.

Comment: @user3439894 now that I know how the output is classified could `xmlstarlet` be used to parse the meta data?